# SQL Server, always rounding up

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to always round up in SQL Server TSQL, such that I have the `Given` and need to return the `Needed Result`:

```
Given         Needed Result
-----------   --------------
25            25
25.1          26
25.001        26
12            12
0.1            1
0.001          1
0              0
```

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like homework, by the way. :/

Comment: @Wheatevo, perhaps I could over complicate the question with needless information regarding the business logic that surrounds this

Comment: Sorry for doubting you, I wish you luck in your business endeavors :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CEILING(Given) should do the trick.

Ceiling just rounds the given number up to the next whole integer.

Comment: I don't think so, [CEILING (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).  Ceiling returns the smallest integer greater than, or equal to, the specified numeric expression. So, `CEILING($123.45)` returns `124.00`

Comment: Isn't that the functionality you're looking for?